# RouteSpecificPool timeout Occuring processing HTTP request while using NIO

Tags: apache, http, asynchronous, nio, nonblocking

We have an application in which we are making an asynchronous request to get the Servlet Response.For making asynchronous Request we are using apache nio

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/tutorial/html/nio.html

I am getting this error.This error is not occuring always and i am not able to figure out when this occurs exactly.

Initially i thought issue was with pool and increased pool size.
But some times it occurs if a send single request only although pool size is 1000.

What can be the possible reason for this error shown below:

```
java.net.ConnectException: null
        at org.apache.http.nio.pool.RouteSpecificPool.timeout(RouteSpecificPool.java:170) [httpcore-nio-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4]
        at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.requestTimeout(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:560) [httpcore-nio-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4]
        at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool$InternalSessionRequestCallback.timeout(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:821) [httpcore-nio-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SessionRequestImpl.timeout(SessionRequestImpl.java:182) [httpcore-nio-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processTimeouts(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:212) [httpcore-nio-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:157) [httpcore-nio-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:350) [httpcore-nio-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4]
        at com.sampleApp.test.nio.NotifierReactor$2.run(NotifierReactor.java:93) [classes/:na]
```